# Simple partial derivative problem

Tags: symbols, mathastext

I have a simple problem with partial derivative symbol, it doesn't work if I try any of these commands:
`\partial`
`\pdiff`
`\pder`

I use sharelatex, and in other projects I could use the `\partial` symbol.
I have no idea what's the problem, could someone help me?
Thank you!

The code (edited in from a comment):

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\linespread{1}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{anysize}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[magyar]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[LGRgreek]{mathastext}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\partial{a}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

The error message: `undefined control sequence`

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Try putting `\show\partial` in the document and then compiling it. You should get a message showing the current definition of the command. What is this message?

Comment: We will need to see an MWE of what you are trying. `$\partial$` should work. The other two are custom commands, I fear. Maybe something like `\newcommand{\pder}[2][]{\frac{\partial#1}{\partial#2}}` for your preamble.

Comment: This is the simple code with usepackages and only trying to use \partial, and the message is undefined control sequence.

\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\linespread{1}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{anysize}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[magyar]{babel}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[LGRgreek]{mathastext}

\usepackage{amssymb}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{subcaption}


\begin{equation}
\partial{a}
\end{equation}
\end{document}

Comment: @Hajnalka -- i transferred your code from a comment to the main text.  (i added `\begin{document}`, which i believe had been omitted unintentionally.)  even as a new user of tex.sx, though, you can always edit your own question, and that is the preferred way of responding to requests in comments.

Comment: The problem is with the `mathastext` package.

Comment: Thank you, I correct my code with \begin{document} too, but still the problem exists.

Answer (score 3):

When using the `LGRgreek` option, `mathastext` package redefines `\partial`. You can either remove the option or reset `\partial` to its original definition by adding the following to your preamble.

```
\makeatletter
\let\partial\mst@origpartial
\makeatother
```

A simple MWE follows:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[LGRgreek]{mathastext}
\makeatletter
\let\partial\mst@origpartial
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\partial{a}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem arises because you're loading the `mathastext` package with the option `LGRgreek`. If you omit this option, the code compiles. If you really need the option `LGRgreek`, the manual suggests issuing the instruction `MTstandardgreek` ahead of equations that feature symbols such as `\partial`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[magyar]{babel}
\usepackage[LGRgreek]{mathastext}

\begin{document}
\begingroup % keep the effect of next instruction local
\MTstandardgreek
\begin{equation}
\partial{a}
\end{equation}
\endgroup
\end{document}
```